# TypeError when opening images from GCP storage to process them with Vision API

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to open/get public images from google cloud storage to process using Vision API. Here is my code.

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

for file_name in list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME):
    response = requests.get(file_name)
    content = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations

    print('Labels:\n')
    for label in labels:
        print(label.description)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gmwill934/PycharmProjects/PDFRekog/functions_vision.py", line 21, in <module>
    image = types.Image(content=content)
TypeError: <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=800x449 at 0x10BA5AD50> has type JpegImageFile, but expected one of: bytes
```

I'm having a hard time trying to open the images from the web, It works when I have my images locally and open using `with open() as image_file....`

[EDIT]

So I've modified my code to this, I converted the image to a `bytes` type, the code runs as expected but no labels show.

```
for file_name in list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME):
    image = imageio.imread(file_name)
    my_array = np.asarray(image)
    content = my_array.tobytes()

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.label_annotations

    print('Labels:\n')
    for label in labels:
        print(label.description)
```

Can a numpy array be converted to bytes? or is there something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `Image` was expecting the binary representation of the pixels. I accomplished it by changing the content variable to the following.

```
content = urlopen(file_name).read()
```

`content` is now returned in binary mode.